# Get the Specific Column and Row of 2 dimentional Array C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

how could i possible get the specific column and row of my 2 dimensional array . It is declared like this

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 6];
```

I want to get the column [2,0](3rd column) and compare it to the [2,1](3rd column,1st row) but if there's no value in [2,1] then I'll compare it to the [3,0](4th column).

I tried doing it like this

```
string[,] table2 = new string[104, 6];
string newPreviousValue2 = "placeholder";
int xIndex2 = 0;
int yIndex2 = 0;

string thirdColumn = table2[3, 0];
string firstRowinThirdColumn = table2[4, 0];

foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
{
    if (table2.GetLength(0) < xIndex2)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (previousValue.Equals(newPreviousValue2) && yIndex2 < table2.GetLength(1) - 1) {

                table2[xIndex2, yIndex2] = previousValue;

                var col = 2;
                var row = 0;

                var origin = table2[col, row];
                var other = table2[col, row + 1] ?? table2[col + 1, row];
                if (origin != null && origin == other)
                {
                    Debug.Log("There's something in 3rd Column 2nd row ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("There's nothing in 3rd column 2nd Row so Move to 4th Column");
                }
            }
            newPreviousValue2 = previousValue;
}
```

But i couldn't get it . What I'm trying to achieve is I'm going to start from the 3rd column but if there is no 2nd row on the 3rd column it will go compare the 3rd column first row to 4th column first row and so on.

## EDIT:

Now i have this data : PP ,B  ,P ,P ,B

This will be like this

[image]

the code @Immersive provided is this

```
var col = 2;
var row = 0;

var origin = table2[col, row];
var other = table2[col, row + 1] ?? table2[col + 1, row];
if (origin != null && origin == other)
{
     Debug.Log("There's something in 3rd Column 2nd row ");
}
else
{
      Debug.Log("There's nothing in 3rd column 2nd Row so Move to 4th Column");
}
```

It always fall to the `else` statement

Comment: Note that `[3,0]` is not referring to the 3rd column, but rather to the second column, as arrays are 0-based.

Comment: @IanH. o sorry my bad

Comment: @IanH, *fourth* column but your point stands

Comment: @Immersive Ah, thanks, messed that one up.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out guys

Comment: why not use a traditional for loop and use the iterator to keep track of index positions as opposed to using foreach?

Comment: @TheGinxx009 What is it you're actually trying to do with this code?

Comment: @Immersive what I am trying to do sir is check if there's a value in my table[2,1]3rd column 2nd row so if it is `null` instead of checking the table[2,1] it will compare the table[3,0]4th column.

Comment: OK. I meant *why* are you doing that?

Comment: I'm doing a baccarat scoreboard sir and there's a rule i am making which is `small road rule` and it works like that.

Comment: OK.  Read your most recent edit.  You aren't actually iterating over the array.  You're moving through whatever `newChar` is, but you're currently unable to track which cell you're looking at.  You are definitely missing at least one `for(;;)` loop.  Your process design (in your head) is incomplete.

Comment: that's why i need your help @Immersive .

Comment: your question doesn't seem complete, you specify what you want to compare (and I agree on a suggestion you shouldn't be using foreach, use a normal for and it'll be more readable), but you don't specify what you want to do with the result, and your code actually modifies the table, so its not clear how to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring boundary checks:

```
var column = 2;
var row = 0;

var origin = table2[column, row];
var other = table2[column, row + 1] ?? table2[column + 1, row];

if ( origin != null && origin == other )
{ }
```

The `??` is called the "coalesce" operator.  It's a shorthand for `(A != null) ? A : B`

Comment: It doesn't check if there's a value in my [2,1]3rd column 1st 2nd row

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Feel free to change the listed indices as required.

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Have expanded a bit for selecting different columns and rows as the origin.  If this isn't your answer then I'm not really sure what your question was.